# Merge Audio with Video

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to merge audio files with video files. 
Here is my effort:

```
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audioUrl options:nil];
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:videoUrl options:nil];

AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionCommentaryTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
                                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionCommentaryTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration) 
                                    ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                     atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo 
                                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) 
                               ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition 
                                                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];   

NSString* videoName = @"export.mov";

NSString *exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
NSURL    *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath]) 
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];
}

_assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
_assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
_assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {      
            // your completion code here
     }       
 }
 ];
```

Everything seems to work fine, but I dont know why this code is not working! 
I am getting assets for both audio and video as well. But I am not able to create export session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`

Also check if you are able to get error using completion code

```
 [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) { 
         switch (_assetExport.status) 
         {
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
             {
                 NSLog (@"FAIL %@",_assetExport.error);
                 break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: 
             {
                 break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled: 
             {
                 NSLog (@"CANCELED");
                 break;
             }
         }
         NSLog(@"Export Status %d-- %@", _assetExport.status, _assetExport.outputURL);
        }
     ];
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me? I have used this code but not able to get video in merging file. I am able to get AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted status for assetSession but not able to see the video. I have checked my video file and it is proper.. also my audio file is proper... but when merging both video is not getting displayed.... Can you tell me what could be the problem??